# How can I always update a dotnet tool to the latest version including previews?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, dotnet-tool

When you want to update or install a dotnet tool you need to explicitly provide the version for preview versions.
It doesn't work in our DevOps environment because we need to be the package always the latest (including preview version).
There's no parameter like `--preview` to update/install the latest version including the preview version.
How can I update a dotnet tool to the latest version including the preview versions?

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported out of the box by the `dotnet tool` command. I wish there was a parameter like `--preview` to include also preview versions when updating/installing a new package. But don't worry there's a workaround for this;

The following PowerShell script gets the latest version of `dotnet-ef` tool including preview versions. Then runs the update command with `--version` parameter.

```powershell
$packageName = "dotnet-ef"

$output = dotnet tool search $packageName --prerelease --take 1
$outputString = ("" + $output)
$indexOfVersionLine = $outputString.IndexOf($packageName)
$latestVersion = $outputString.substring($indexOfVersionLine + $packageName.length).trim().split(" ")[0].trim()

Write-Host "Updating "$packageName" to" $latestVersion
dotnet tool update -g $packageName --version $latestVersion
```

There's an active feature request on the dotnet-sdk repository for this requirement  https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16669

This is how we achieve it in our DevOps pipeline:
https://gist.github.com/ebicoglu/177f48f5fad1bcc49645c0939af4ae76#file-update-abp-cli-tools-preview-ps1